# Any ui library for swipe button in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a swipe button on my android application,
I found a library which is good but doesn't really fit well with my use case (https://github.com/cortinico/slidetoact)

So I am looking for any alternatives to this library

Comment: Would be better if you attach a use case sample for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should say why the original option doesn't fit you well. But anyways, this is another alternative library https://github.com/MAXDeliveryNG/slideview